# Ignite 2.14 and TransientSerializable Annotation

Tags: java, ignite, transient

Has support for TransientSerializable annotation been removed from Ignite 2.14?

I have used this feature in 2.11 but it seems to be missing in 2.14.

If so, what is the current replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TransientSerializable` annotation is still available in Ignite 2.14.0. You can check it on GitHub [here](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/ignite-2.14/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/internal/util/TransientSerializable.java).

Actually, I should mention that it's a part of Ignite's internal API and its public usage should be avoided.

Comment: I had an error in my build that prevented the annotation from being used.  Thank you for pointing out it should not be used.  Is there a proper way to tell ignite to ignore certain fields?